# Cron: Execute python script, capture stdout & stderr and send via msmtp

Tags: scripting, cron, python, pipe

I try this for almost 4 hours now, in different ways. I googled a lot, but nothing I try work as expected.

I have a simple .msmtprpc file, that allows me to send mails like this:

```
echo -e "Subject: foobar\r\n\r\nContent" | msmtp my_mail@gmail.com
```

However, I can't seem to concatenate the full output of a Python script as content of the message.

This command:

```
( echo -e "Subject: aaa\r\n\r\n" ; python foo.py 2>&1; ) | msmtp foobar@gmail.com
```

works in my terminal, but not as a cron command. Perhaps we can improve it ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: make it bash script and run command inside it. It will ease your life.

And check your path to python script, i believe you should point absolute path.

Comment: maybe you have misconfiogured the cron user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Navern suggested, I put my whole command in to a bash script, then ran the bash script from cron. And, of course, an absolute path was necessary.

Comment: It's me who told you about absolute path:) Glad that it worked for you:)

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that ^^